# MariaDB vs Mysql Query Trouble

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Recently we change our database system from MySql to MariaDB and we are having some troubles with one query...

```
SELECT
    (SELECT
        IFNULL(label, '') FROM (
            SELECT
                ( SELECT label FROM llx_categorie WHERE   rowid = @r And type = 0 ) AS label,
                @r As r,
                ( Select  @r := fk_parent FROM llx_categorie WHERE   rowid = r And type = 0 ) As parent,
                @l := @l - 1 As lvl
            FROM( SELECT  @r := 732, @l := 5, @cl := 0 ) vars,
                llx_categorie h
            Where (@l > 0) And type = 0 And @r > 0 And label IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY parent ASC 
        )  as t1
        LIMIT 0,1 ) as catlevel1,
     (SELECT
        IFNULL(label, '') FROM (
            SELECT
                ( SELECT label FROM llx_categorie WHERE   rowid = @r And type = 0 ) AS label,
                @r As r,
                ( Select  @r := fk_parent FROM llx_categorie WHERE   rowid = r And type = 0 ) As parent,
                @l := @l - 1 As lvl
            FROM( SELECT  @r := 732, @l := 5, @cl := 0 ) vars,
                llx_categorie h
            Where (@l > 0) And type = 0 And @r > 0 And label IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY parent ASC 
        )  as t1
        LIMIT 1,1 ) as catlevel2
```

It's just a simple query for getting parent categories from category id @r732.

If we run this on MySql returns as expected, example.

```
+----------------------+--------------+
| catlevel1            | catlevel2    |
+----------------------+--------------+
| Todas las categorías | Sonido-Audio |
+----------------------+--------------+
```

But in MariaDB returns this.

```
+----------------------+--------------+
| catlevel1            | catlevel2    |
+----------------------+--------------+
| Todas las categorías | NULL         |
+----------------------+--------------+
```

Anyone knows how it can be possible? Or possible solutions? Missing configuration enabled o server? I´m getting crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you selecting from `llx_categorie h`?  I don't see any uses of `h`.  Either remove the table or add qualification to the appropriate fields and spell out how the `JOIN` is done.  Or is it a "cross join"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not true:

> It's just a simple query

;)

Secondly, after i did some research into this (it suprised me), i noticed there were quite a lot of different results when querying mySQL or MariaDB, but most of them seem to be connected to `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY`. Somebod elaborately also pointed out that mariaDB is more strict(=more ANSI compliant) with SIGNED and UNSIGNED Types. Maybe this helps you into the right direction.

I don't know the solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for clues, i´m still looking for a solution, between those databases engines.

:)

Comment: And yet you checked this of as "The Answer"??

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem stems from something like this:

Given a subquery with an `ORDER BY` and an outer query without an `ORDER BY`...

In old MySQL, the inner ordering was still valid in the outer``SELECT`.

In MariaDB, the outer ordering, not being specified, is unpredictable.

Possible solution:  Move `ORDER BY  parent ASC` out one level.

Another possible solution (for MariaDB):  Set optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off' (or optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off,derived_with_keys=off', depending on the structure of your table).  [Reference](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/).

I suspect it was just coincidence that you got the 'correct' catlevel1, but not catlevel2.

Also, get rid of `llx_categorie h` if you are not using it.